# Attempted to read or write protected memory connecting to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

This is the error I'm getting:

> Failed to connect to server MYSERVER. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. (System.Data)

I was getting this error while using entity framework to run any query, e.g. any line like this:

```
var AllRows = context.MyTableRows.ToList();
```

I thought it was an EF problem, but then I tried to use the Transact Sql Editor in VS2012 to connect to the database so I could query it, and I get the same error when trying to connect.

But I've got other, non-Microsoft querying tools that can connect to the database and query it, without causing the error. So I think the problem is somewhere in the Microsoft drivers, or System.Data.SqlClient, but I can't figure out where the problem is.

**Update:** I tried connecting in LinqPad to the same server, and when I try to connect it just hangs.

**Update:** The stack trace is quite long, and looks like this:

```
at SNIAddProvider(SNI_Conn* , ProviderNum , Void* )
at SNINativeMethodWrapper.SNIAddProvider(SafeHandle pConn, ProviderEnum providerEnum, UInt32& info)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ConsumePreLoginHandshake(Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean& marsCapable)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure)
at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection()
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__2[TResult](IEnumerable`1 sequence)
at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot)
at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[S](Expression expression)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
```

...lines in my app that try to execute an EF query...

Comment: Can you post your connection string?

Comment: The connection string is: "data source=SERVER;initial catalog=DATABASE;user id=USER;password=PASSWORD;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework.  But that's used by the EF code.  In VS2012, there's a dialog that prompts for the credentials, and uses its own connection string, and that fails in the same way.

Comment: Is the SQL Server on the same machine or separate?  What version of SQL Server?  How many rows are in the table that you are pulling back?

Comment: Try reinstalling your Sql Native provider dll's.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: I don't think you can.  System.Data.SqlClient is part of .NET, which is part of Windows 8, and I can't find anything to uninstall and reinstall.

Comment: Well they may be corrupt so you should talk to your desktop admins about how to address that possibilty.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: *I'm* my desktop admin and I can't see what to do.  I could of course reinstall VS or Windows, but that would cost hours or days.

Comment: @Geek: It's on a separate machine, to a network about 1000 miles away.  This happens on connection, before trying to get any rows from any user table.

Comment: Do you get the same issue if you run Visual Studio as an administrator?  If you do - it sounds like a corrupt driver.  The other way to check is to try to connect to SQL Express locally.

Comment: This looks like a bug in System.Data.dll (this type of error comes from unsafe .NET code or underlying unmanaged code). Check you have the latest System.Data assembly in your process, and if this is the case you should report it to Microsoft Connect: http://connect.microsoft.com/

Comment: @Geek: I tried running VS as an admin and get the same error.

Comment: @SimonMourier: I've tried everything I can think of to repair or update the installation, but there's no way to do it, because it's baked into Windows 8.  I guess I could report the bug, but I wouldn't expect anything anytime soon from Microsoft.

Comment: Can you connect to a local SQL / SQL Express instance?

Comment: Try uninstalling / re-installing your NIC card drivers on the machine / update the drivers.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting the SQL Server?

Comment: @Geek: I can try that, but it scares me because if I break my NIC card, then I can't get on the net to fix anything.

Comment: @cbeckner: I don't own the SQL Server, but I will reach out to that team and ask them.

Comment: Is this happening only when debugging in VS?

Comment: @ArjunSol: It happens while running the app AND using the Sql Query connection in the Server Explorer in VS.

Comment: Best resource I can find is here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8789ea67-fbc5-4a7b-a4eb-d4a8a050d5c1/attempt-to-read-or-write-protected-memory-this-is-often-an-indicating-that-other-memory-is-corrupt

Comment: Have you tried defragmeting those files with the Microsoft defragment utility?

Comment: Actually, sorry, I meant using Chkdsk...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, after a week tearing my hair out and trying all sorts of desperate measures, I was finally able to fix this by uninstalling a program that was monitoring network traffic (Cucusoft Net Guard).  This program seems to interfere with something in the packet traffic and it was causing my error.  Uninstalling this app fixed the problem, but, curiously, turning it off did not.  It must have installed a low level filter that was in place and caused the problem even when the app was not running.

Comment: There is now a KB article that describes this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2915689

Comment: WideCap also causes this.

Answer (score 20):

I had the same problem after upgrading from .NET 4.5 to .NET 4.5.1. As soon as I tried to access anything using Entity Framework, I got that error. What fixed it for me was running this command (in an admin prompt):

`netsh winsock reset`

And then restart.

Comment: If your problem recurs after the winsock reset -- see KB 2568167 and run `netsh WinSock Show Catalog` when your system works.  Then run it when you're crashed and compare.  See if your AV software uses LSP's and is injecting the incompatibility.

Comment: You are a life saver. At least 20 hours across multiple employees were wasted to troubleshoot this very obscure and sudden problem causing major business application (anything with a SQL connections) to stop working. Thanks god only 1 PC upgraded to this version and that we found the solution before more PCs followed.

Comment: +1 agree. Would like to add I installed Visual Studio 2013 (VS2013) and then as a result Sql Server Management Studio (SSMS) and Visual Studio 2010 (VS2010) just completely stopped working. LIVE SAVER.

Comment: This happened for me after installing SQL 2014 then uninstalling SQL 2012.  Only happened for me when running 64-bit apps: 32-bit apps seemed to be just fine. This was a life saver - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Per [this](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/dennis/archive/2009/06/08/attempted-to-read-or-write-protected-memory-in-a-net-application.aspx), "Anyway, the solution was to enable JIT optimization. In other words, in Visual Studio 2008 choose “Tools” and then “Options”. Select “Debugging” and “General” and find the line that says “Suppress JIT optimization on module load”. This kind of makes sure that the debugger and the JIT compiled code aren’t running out of sync because the JIT compiler is such a super duper optimizer of your code. This did the trick."

Check that out.  It it doesn't work, try to connect to the database using SQL Server Management Studio.  If you can, the error is likely Visual Studio related.

Comment: I tried it with this setting both checked and unchecked and get the error both ways.

Comment: @JoshuaFrank Darn.  Did you try connecting to the database through management studio?

Comment: I just downloaded and try this and I do get the same error.  Curiously, if I go to advanced options and change the protocol from TCP/IP to Named Pipes, I get a different error: 
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 1326)...The user name or password is incorrect

Comment: So now I'm wondering if something is messed up on the Sql Server.  Apparently, this can be caused by firewall issues.

Comment: Yeah, you can get cut off not only by firewall, but you can also configure the server to conect using TCP or Named Pipes.  Talk to your DBAs and check what they have configured.

Comment: @JoshuaFrank  Good question.  I am worried your .net framework is corrupt since both management studio and visual studio are crashing.  Can you connect on a co workers computer?

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue with my SQL Server 2014 Express Edition when I am connecting to my remote sql server.

Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. (System.Data)

I had upgraded to .net frame work form 4.5 to 4.5.1 after upgrading I was unable to connect to remote sql server. Now I had uninstalled the 4.5.1 frame work and now its working fine.