# How can I repair .NET Framework 4.0 on Windows 8?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-8, sqlclient

While trying debug [my real problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837510/attempted-to-read-or-write-protected-memory-connecting-to-sql-server]), I'm trying to repair the .NET framework, because it looks like something in System.Data.SqlClient is hosed.  But you can't uninstall this because it's part of the OS in Windows8, and you can't install it because it's already installed, and so I can't find any way to fix my problem.  I suppose I could reinstall the whole OS, but that's way too painful.

Comment: First check are you having .NET Framework 3.5 or 2.0? I had the same problem. And when I checked it in WebMatrix, I saw that the Framework 2 was missing. I installed that, and then all the errors vanished. SqlCe, ASP.NET Razor! They all. the issue is that Framework 2.0 isn't installed in Windows 8.

Comment: Does the [.NET repair tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30135) do anything useful?

Comment: @RogerRowland: It offers the ability to clean up versions 1.0, 1.1, and All Versions.  But it's so full of warnings about how dangerous is that I'm afraid to try it.  If I remove All Versions, will I be able to reinstall them?

Comment: What have you got to lose? Maybe there's a system restore point you can go back to instead?

Comment: @RogerRowland: Everything else works.  All my apps, including VS, and my other dev projects.  So I'm really afraid to break all of them.

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan: I opened the web platform installer and .NET 2.0 isn't even an option.  And when I downloaded it from Microsoft, the installer didn't appear to do anything.

Comment: For Windows 8, you should have .NET 4.5 anyway as it's a direct replacement for 4.0. In my Win8 there's a "repair" option from Add/remove programs in control panel. I think whatever you try - do a full backup first then you can't get any worse than now.

Comment: Would system file checker check these components? (sfc /scannow)

Comment: @RogerRowland: I do have 4.5, but it doesn't seem to help.  I also went and tried the repair tool, and it didn't appear to do anything.  I think it won't touch versions of the OS that are part of the OS.

Comment: @Alan: Not sure, but I'm trying it now.

Comment: @Alan: sfc ran and did actually produce some issues that might be relevant, but I'm not sure how to tell.  I see an entry like this: [DIRSD OWNER WARNING] Directory [ml:520{260},l:112{56}]"\??\C:\Windows\Inf\.NET Data Provider for SqlServer\0000" is not owned but specifies SDDL in component NETFX4CLIENTCoreComp, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_IA32_ON_WIN64.  But I have no idea what that means, and Google isn't finding much.

Comment: @JoshuaFrank Well at least it's a start... I guess worst case scenario might be a OS reinstall/repair. Please do a backup of your files! I had explorer's search get corrupted on me and crash repeatedly, I thought it was a bizarre problem, backed up files, reinstalled, a week later my SSD failed for good. You never know what could be caused by hardware failure! Especially if anything else is getting corrupted

Answer (score 7):

To Repair corrupted Windows files in Windows 8, open a [command prompt with admin rights](https://superuser.com/questions/497252/how-to-access-the-administrator-command-prompt-in-windows-8) and run [this DISM command](http://blogs.technet.com/b/joscon/archive/2012/09/26/fixing-component-store-corruption-in-windows-8-and-windows-server-2012.aspx):

```
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
```

This downloads the clean files and installs them correctly.